# Math equation for random float?

Tags: ios, math, floating-point, arc4random

I have this method:

```
- (float)randomFloatBetween:(float)num1 andLargerFloat:(float)num2 {
return ((float)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX) * num2-num1 + num1;
}
```

And I am curious that if it is possible instead of using conditionals for the following:
I want to make a random float for my game like this:

```
When the score is:
Score 0-20: I want a float between 4.0-4.5 using the above method
Score 21-40: I want a float between 3.0-3.5 using the above method
Score 41-60: I want a float between 2.5-3.0 using the above method
Score 61+: I want a float between 2.0-2.5 using the above method
```

Now I know I can use conditionals to do that but is there any math equation that would be easier than doing that?

Thanks!

Edit1:

```
    - (float)determineFloat {
    if (score <= 60)
    {
        //Gets the tens place digit, asserting >= 0.
        int f = fmax(floor( (score - 1) / 10 ), 0);

        switch (f)
        {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            {
                // return float between 4.0 and 4.5
                [self randomFloatBetween:4.0 andLargerFloat:4.5];
            }
            case 2:
            case 3:
            {
                // return float between 3.0 and 3.5
                [self randomFloatBetween:3 andLargerFloat:3.5];
            }
            case 4:
            case 5:
            {
                // return float between 2.5 and 3.0
                [self randomFloatBetween:2.5 andLargerFloat:3];
            }
            default:
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // return float between 2.0 and 2.5
        [self randomFloatBetween:2.0 andLargerFloat:2.5];
    }
    return;
}
```

Hows this?. Also are you sure this is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, since the relation is not continuous. When you have this kind of requirement, it is better to just use conditionals or a switch statement. You and anyone reading or debugging the code would then know exactly what the function is doing. Using some sort of mathematical function in this case, which would be extremely complicated, at best, is most likely going to slow the process down.

Possibility using a switch:

```
-(float)determineFloat:(float)score
{
    if (score <= 60)
    {
        //Gets the tens place digit, asserting >= 0.
        int f = (int)fmax(floor( (score - 1) / 10.0f ), 0);

        switch (f)
        {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            {
                return [self randomFloatBetween:4.0 andLargerFloat:4.5];
            }
            case 2:
            case 3:
            {
                return [self randomFloatBetween:3.0 andLargerFloat:3.5];
            }
            case 4:
            case 5:
            {
                return [self randomFloatBetween:2.5 andLargerFloat:3.0];
            }
            default:
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return [self randomFloatBetween:2.0 andLargerFloat:2.5];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
float myScore = 33;
float randomFloat = [self determineFloat:myScore];
```

Now, `randomFloat` will be a value between 3 and 3.5.

Comment: What would be the most efficient way with using conditionals, should I do if->else if->else if, etc.... ?

Comment: No I do not have a maximum score

Comment: I added a code sample. I intended this to be in its own function, but you can use a variable instead of a return.

Comment: Should I use a void method? I am trying to do that and it is saying void method should not return a value! Edit: Nevermind instead of void, I am using float.

Comment: You would need to return a float, since that's what you are generating based on the score.

Comment: You need to add `return` before your calls to `randomFloatBetween`.

Comment: How often will you be calling `determineFloat`?

Comment: No: `return [self randomFloatBetween:2.0 andLargerFloat:2.5];` for all of them. And remove the `return` on the last line.

Comment: Could be a few times a second. I made an edit to it after I posted it, check it once more. And why should I do between 2.0 and 2.5 for each? Your comments say otherwise :)

Comment: Don't change the ranges for each, just add the `return`s before each of the calls to `randomFloatBetween`.

Comment: ok now I am [super confused]; :P Can you edit your code to explain what I should do instead? Then I will accept your answer! :D

Comment: thanks! Accepted! And your positive this is the best and most efficient way to do this with all the info I gave you right?

Comment: The efficiency difference between my code and a bunch of if-else statements is negligible. One is no better than the other.

Comment: Alright but this way is much better on the eyes! Thanks again!